# Better Approach to Dashboards on TV

Tags: dashboard, displays, data-display

Im currently redesigning some dashboards for a team.The Goal for this redesign is to be able to see which servers are down just from looking at the dashboards.  The team would be viewing these on their desktop but at the same time have a 42 inch tv on the walls so if they are away from their desktop they can see them on the TV.

What the desktop version does is warns the users when servers have timed out by showing a red bar above and letting them know to check the timed out servers. Two set of users would be using this. UserOne uses the dashboards on tab A while UserTwo uses the dashboards on Tab B. The dashboards are displayed by having three show on every row while the timed out servers are the ones shown first in top.

Now going back to the TV I'm trying to find a good approach to show Both Users their dashboards on the tv. Since the tv is NOT touch screen i was thinking of having it configured where the tabs would switch every 30 seconds showing the timed out servers for UserOne for 30 seconds and then switching to the other tab and showing UserTwo their servers. Would this be a good approach, I have not tested this yet but would like to know if anyone has worked with this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 42-Inch TV has more space to work with. Combine them into one view

I would suggest, if at all possible, to **combine the tab displays into one**. A 42-inch TV has much more real estate to work with, so fonts and images can afford to be *slightly* smaller.

#### Still want the two different views? Timer needs a visual indicator

If it is not possible or prudent to combine both displays into one (because, perhaps, people cannot stand close to the TV, so the elements must be large, or if the TV must show information to a large room) and you would like to proceed with your timer implementation, at the very least, **provide a visual indicator for when the screens will cycle**.